# Count appearance of a variable in another file

Tags: text-processing

I do have the following situation:

File1 looks like:

```
A  
B  
C
```

File2 looks like:

```
chr1 \t 1234523 \t A  
chr3 \t 1234231 \t A  
chr6 \t 121233 \t A  
chr1 \t 1126685 \t B  
chr1 \t 15834523 \t B  
chr4 \t 12345647 \t C  
chr12 \t 1456523 \t C
```

I would like to get the output:

```
A \t 3 
B \t 2  
C \t 2
```

I know that I could do it like

```
grep A File2 | wc -l
```

However, than I would need to do it for each single line in File1 (which are 700).

How can I automate that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `\t`s are actually tabs, and that the occurrences are on the same column, and that A only matches A, not AA. Let `a` be the file with A,B,C and `b` the file where you want to count matches on (the second one you provided).

- First, you need to get only the possible matches from `b`, ignoring everything else. This is the third column of `b`, so we can use `cut` that is, well, intended to cut parts of a file

  cut -f 3 b
- Then, you need to turn this into a list of occurences and their counts: you can sort and use `uniq` to count those, on the output of `cut`

  sort | uniq -c
- Finally, you did this for *all* values in `b`, but you only want those from `a`. You can use `join` which joins two different files on common fields (in this case, the first and only field of `a` (it seems to do that by default) and the second field (`2`) of `b`, which is the second file (`-2`)

  join -2 2 a result-from-b

You can chain this in several different ways, a possible way is using named pipes from `bash`'s process substitution:

```
join -2 2 a <(cut -f 3 b | sort | uniq -c)
```

This should at least be better than individual greps, as you only process b thrice (remove other columns, `sort`, and `uniq`) and then I suppose the join will only read each file once, as it requires the inputs to be sorted. Of course this relies on the assumptions I made (and you also have to sort `a`, but that's just `<(sort a)` instead of `a` if it was not sorted before.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly well! And also thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @user30012 if this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your sample input that you want to count each distinct value in the last field of tab-separated records. Here's an awk snippet that does this.

```
awk -F '\t' '
     {++a[$NF]}
     END {for (x in a) {print x "\t" a[x]}}
' File2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a while loop

```
while read arg < FILE1; do echo -n -e "$arg\t"; grep "$arg" FILE2 | wc -l; done
```

This will read FILE1 and for each line the for loop will store the string into the variable $arg.

It will then echo the $arg (-n means don't insert a line return (\n) at the end, -e means execute excaped characters).

Then it will display the number of occurrences it found $arg in FILE2.

Comment: No need to pipe to `wc -l` and count lines; `grep` can already count occurrences with the `-c` option.

Comment: @laebshade you're right, however, I used `wc -l` in case the search string matched more than once per line in FILE2.

Comment: That would skew the results.  If you have more than one instance per line, suddenly your counted results aren't accurate.